# Is it possible to open transactions in OrientDB through gremlin server?

Tags: transactions, orientdb, gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I noticed by looking at the java source code of the orientdb-gremlin library that it seems to be only a wrapper that gets the gremlin commands and translates into orientdb SQL queries.

I am trying to use gremlin with orientdb in **javascript (NodeJs)** and for that I am using the `gremlin` js library. I can connect fine to the gremlin server (I'm using the one shipped with OrientDB 3.0.14) but I could not yet make transactions work for two reasons:
1) `gremlin` js library does not have the tx() method in the Graph object.
2) I thought: *"I can add it there, but let me see first in gremlin console if OrientDB supports opening a transaction from gremlin server"*. So trying from the gremlin console does not seem to work either (remember that I **don't** want to use the `orientdb-gremlin` plugin as in javascript I won't be able to use it):

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote-secure.yaml
gremlin> :> g.tx().open()
gremlin> :> g.tx().isOpen()
```

This last command results in `false`, so there is no transaction opened.

Is there any way to span an OrientDB 3.0.14 transaction through gremlin server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `orientdb-gremlin` supports `g.tx()` (really `graph.tx()` which is called by `g.tx()` - i.e. the `Graph` instance needs to support it) then the only way you use transaction from javascript would be if you submitted string-based scripts to Gremlin Server and did so via [session](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#sessions). I think that's potentially why you're not seeing `isOpen()` return `true` as you've connected to the server in a sessionless fashion - you can change that by doing:

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session
```

which is discussed [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#console-sessions).

Submitting string-based scripts is not really the recommended way to interact with Gremlin Server. It is a far better development experience to just "write Gremlin" in your native programming language rather than embedding Gremlin in strings. I would reconsider this approach if you can and try not to rely on graph-specific transactions. They make your code far [less portable](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#staying-agnostic).